# babel-preset-es2015 error install

Tags: node.js, error-handling, webpack, babeljs

Two weeks ago I had a project file with webpack config and `node_moudels`. It was running great, but today i reopened project file and `node_modules` file were missing. So I run `npm i` command to reinstall my dependencies. Error has occured during the instalation of `babel-preset-2015`. I just can´t install that module inside my project directory (it throws error each time)! Afterwards I tried to install `babel-preset-2015` separately at my desktop and it was ok. But I have noticed that `babel-preset-2015` is no longer in single file, but multiple files were installed inside `node_module` directory instead. Did I miss some important babel update or what the hell happened? I am using win7, node version is 4.2.6.

Comment: Which error do you have when you try to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing multiple directories on the `node_modules/` path after installing a single dependency is probably due to version difference of NPM between your two environments. [NPM v3](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3)  will now attempt to collocate all non-conflicting dependencies under a common root, which produces a different layout than what you've previously grown accustomed to.